# WSO2 APIM enabling response caching doesn't work

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

So lately I wanted to test the response caching feature for a project
So I created a new API in my Publisher and created a mock backend that simulates a 3 second delay when sending the response.

I enabled response caching like in the docs and made it so that the cache timeout is about 15 seconds.

[image: pic]

**Problem :** It doesn't work, I read that WSO2 is supposed to only send the request to the backend the first time and then retrieve the response from the cache the second time, but it keeps requesting the backend every time and the request keeps taking 3 seconds

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Response caching is to cache backend response. It is not clear why did you add a delay for that.

Comment: I added the delay to simulate the backend taking time to send the response so that when I enable the caching I get a faster response the second time – It's for a demonstration

Comment: @Hyperion what's the APIM version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Response Caching works under the following conditions

> When a message enters a message flow, the Cache mediator checks whether the incoming message is similar to a previous message that was received within a specified period of time. [Reference](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Cache+Mediator)

This means the request needs to be identical including the request Headers and Body as the previous request to work and take the response from the cache.

You can also check the behaviour of whether the response is retrieved from the cache or fetched from the Backend by enabling the Synapse Wire Logs in the API Manager server. You can follow [Enabling Gateway Wire Logs](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/administer/logging-and-monitoring/logging/setting-up-logging/#gateway-wire-logs) doc to enable the Wire logs in your environment and verify whether the response is fetched from the cache or being fetched from the actual backend itself. For the response caching scenario, the wire log will not have the intermediate request and response logs.